# print foo by modifying the below piece of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Without hardcoding the string, 'foo', how can i modify the code above so that it prints out 'foo 1', 'foo 2', and 'foo 3' each on separate lines.

```
const obj = {
  x: 'foo',
  f: function() {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
      console.log(this.x, num);
    });
  }
}

obj.f();
```

Comment: Remember that the posting guidelines tell you not to post images of text. It's so important that it's even in giant bold lettering. Head on over to [how to post a good question](/help/how-to-ask) just as a quick refresher.

Comment: done. please check now

Comment: you're passing a plain function into the forEach, so the meaning of `this` is "whatever it is at runtime", which would be `window` (you can confirm this by logging `console.log(this, num)` instead). You probably want an arrow function, to preserve the meaning of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic "function" declarations will bind to the caller's "this" environment instead of how most languages do it.  Traditionally, this can be fixed with the `bind` method on a function as follows:

```
const obj = {
     x: 'foo',
      f: function() {
          [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
              console.log(this.x, num);
          }.bind(this))
        }
    };
```

The simpler approach is to just use the new arrow syntax, which will bind the function as you would naturally expect.

This line:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
```

To this:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach((num)=> {
```

Comment: specifically: because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) preserve whatever `this` refers to at declaration time (e.g. inside your object's code, it refers to your object) rather than what it is at execution time (which case be wildly different, and in this case is the `window` object when the function runs)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - changing the inner function passed to `forEach`  from `function` to arrow syntax addresses the OP's issue.  But can you extend my understanding by explaining why changing the outer function (the one bound to `f`) to arrow syntax as well reverts the fix?  that is ``f: () => {[1, 2, 3].forEach((num) => {console.log(this.x, num);});`` then invoking `obj.f()` prints "undefined" instead of "foo"

Comment: Because if we replace the outer function, `this` is still globalThis at declare time. The function we pass into the forEach doesn't get declared until we're inside `obj.f()`, where `this` is bound to `obj` (if we use a normal function).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  x: 'foo',
  f: function() {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(num) {
      console.log(`${obj.x} ${num}`);
    });
  }
}

obj.f();
```